# SQL Server fails to start after moving database files: "Could not open file .. Access is denied"

Tags: sql-server, restart

I have moved the data files to new location but while moving I have given the wrong data file name. So it is throwing error

A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'D:\Programfiles\Microsoft Sql server\MSSQL2008\Data\MSDBLog.ldf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

FCB::Open failed: Could not open file D:\Programfiles\Microsoft Sql server\MSSQL2008\Data\modellog.ldf for file number 2.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).

these were the errors I was getting after the data file movement.

Please suggest me what should be done to start the sql server service.

Comment: Advice: **don't just move the SQL Server files around!** Those are managed by SQL Server - let it handle its files as needed, don't fiddle around with them!

Comment: @marc_s: disk space was very less so moved files to another disk by using alter database modify file command. and I tried to restart the service but i was not able to..